# Make a restart command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot in Discord.js and I'd like to create a restart command but I don't know how can I do... Could you help me?

I have tried that but it doesn't work:

```js
client.destroy()
client.login("Token")
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks correct, only thing I noticed is that both are async functions and you don't await them or similiar. You got two options to do this:

Asnyc:

```
await client.destroy();
client.login("Token");
```

Or Sync using `.then` on the Promise:

```
client.destroy().then(() => client.login("Token"));
```

You can read more on Promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: At first it didn't work for me since i was using an eval command wich was simpler and faster and i got the erro "Request to use token but token was unanvailable to the client" but then i tried with a real command and it worked ! So thanks